# casting using llvm::dyn_cast cause in failed assertion

Tags: llvm, assertion

ERROR MESSAGE :
llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:240: typename llvm::cast_retty::ret_type llvm::cast(Y*) [with X = llvm::PointerType, Y = llvm::Type, typename llvm::cast_retty::ret_type = llvm::PointerType*]: Assertion `isa(Val) && "cast() argument of incompatible type!"' failed.

CODE :

```
Value *op1 = x->getOperand(0);

bool flag1;

if(ConstantInt *CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(op)){

  flag1=CI->isOne();

}
```

I searched on google and found that this was a bug but fixed. I recently downloaded the source and compiled it. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Are you positive `op1` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with _or_null as well. Same error!

Comment: instead of dyn_cast, I just used (ConstantInt *) to typecast after isa<> check. Also, isOne() was giving error(I don't know why?) so I used getValue() and compared with 1.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved after using llvm 3.4 stable release. I was using latest code earlier.